# openssl - Decrypt File with PCKS#7 signature not working on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, openssl

I have a script that runs via console this command:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -verify -inform DER -in "/var/www/LCO/LCO_2016-12-06_2.XML" -noverify -out "/var/www/LCO/US_LCO_2016-12-06_2.XML"
```

We have been using it with CentOS, but now that I'm doing refactoring of related code that uses it in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I'm getting this:

```
Error reading S/MIME message
140123614328480:error:07069041:memory buffer routines:BUF_MEM_grow_clean:malloc failure:buffer.c:169:
140123614328480:error:0D06B041:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO:malloc failure:a_d2i_fp.c:255:
```

The XML is an 441MB file and I have 2GB of RAM.

I've got to do it inside a CentOS virtual machine with 1GB of RAM.